# Java generic method: return specific type (without unchecked cast warning)

Tags: java, generics, unchecked-cast

Given a collection `c` with elements of type `T` (or `T`'s subtypes) return some element `e` of type `R` from `c` so that `R` is a subtype of `T`.

Motivation: I want to use specific methods of `R` on `e`.

**UPDATE:** From the [aioobe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76636862/3868454) added to the requirements acceptance of `R`'s subtypes for `e`.

Here is my working implementation:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ReturnSpecificTypeFromGeneric {

    public static <T, R extends T> R findFirstElementOfType(
            List<? extends T> elements,
            Class<R> requiredClass
    ) {
        for (T element : elements) {
            if (requiredClass.isAssignableFrom(element.getClass())) {
                // WARNING: Unchecked cast: 'T' to 'R'
                //noinspection unchecked
                return (R) element; // [1]
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Mammal> mammals = new ArrayList<>();
        mammals.add(new Elephant());
        mammals.add(new WhiteRhino());
        mammals.add(new Rhino());
        Rhino rhino = findFirstElementOfType(mammals, Rhino.class);
        System.out.println(rhino.getClass()); // returns: class WhiteRhino
    }
}

class Mammal {}
class Elephant extends Mammal {}
class Rhino extends Mammal {}
class WhiteRhino extends Rhino {}
```

**Questions:**

1. Is this a right approach?
2. Can the **unchecked cast** (marked as `[1]`) be avoided, and how, and should it be cared about?
3. Other solutions if possible.

Comment: What is happening if you declare `result` as `R` not as `T'?

Comment: @Jens I will need to use `result = (R) element;` below in the `if`, and the unchecked cast will be there :(

Comment: @Jens Good point, thanks! I simplified the code, but this is not the solution :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. That code looks reasonable to me.
2. You could "hide" the cast by instead using `requiredClass.cast(element)`.
3. Basically the same solution, but you could express it using streams as follows:

   ```
   public static <T, R extends T> R findFirstElementOfType(
           List<? extends T> elements,
           Class<R> requiredClass
   ) {
       return elements.stream()
               .filter(requiredClass::isInstance)
               .findFirst()
               .map(requiredClass::cast)
               .orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);
   }
   ```

   or `.orElse(null)` in the end, if you want the exact behavior of your original snippet.